ClamAV configuration: failed to open log file /var/log/freshclam.log
I use ClamAV on Monterey.
Previously installed it using Homebrew, and so far it works OK, like sudo freshclam to update the signature database, or clamscan to scan an USB disk.
Now I switched to MacPorts, and after installing ClamAV and editing it's config (/usr/local/etc/clamav/freshclam.conf):
# Path to the database directory.
# WARNING: It must match clamd.conf's directive!
# Default: hardcoded (depends on installation options)
DatabaseDirectory /var/lib/clamav

# Path to the log file (make sure it has proper permissions)
# Default: disabled
UpdateLogFile /var/log/freshclam.log

Let's try to update the signature database:
$ sudo freshclam
ERROR: Failed to open log file /var/log/freshclam.log: Permission denied
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/freshclam.log).
ERROR: initialize: libfreshclam init failed.
ERROR: Initialization error!

Running ls -la at /var/log gives this:
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root             wheel                   0 Sep 20 21:12 freshclam.log

What's wrong here? I thought sudo freshclam is enough for gaining the required permission?

I would temporarily allow anyone to write that log and then check what user runs the daemon once it’s running stably. Then make sure that user is in a group that can write to the log file? chmod a+w /var/log/freshclam.log this lets you not have to understand why the script run as root isn’t running everything it influences or starts as root.

Ah I see... needs a chmod a+w
